# Cannot add records to sqlite table: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I use EntityFramework SQLite and got stuck with weird bug. I searched for the similar problems, but no solution suits my case.

In my real project it does not work at all. (with the same exception) In the example I made when I execute code first time it works fine (when db is just created), when I run it again I got exception:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'
```

Minimum reproducible sample can be found [here](https://github.com/Mogikan/SQLiteEFGuidBug).

The code is rather trivial:

```
        using (var ctx = new SqliteDbContext("data.db"))
        {
            ctx.Database.Migrate();                
                ctx.UserReferencesData.Add(new UserReferencesData()
                {
                    ColumnId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    MetadataId = -2,
                    RowId = 1,
                    ColumnType = 1,
                    StringValue = "asdf",
                });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Model is also rather simple, but I suspect that it has to do with particular column or index, since other tables works fine:

```
[Table("UserReferencesData")]
    [Index(nameof(RowId))]
    public class UserReferencesData
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int MetadataId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int RowId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Guid ColumnId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int ColumnType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        //type 0
        public DateTime? DateValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        //type 1
        public string StringValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        //type 2
        public int? IntValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        //type 3
        public double? DoubleValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        //type 4
        public bool? BoolValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        //type 5
        public decimal? DecimalValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

dbcontext:

```
public class SqliteDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private string _dbPath = @"data.db";
        public SqliteDbContext(string dbPath)
        {
            _dbPath = dbPath;
        }
        //ctor for migration
        public SqliteDbContext(DbContextOptions<SqliteDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var path = $"Data Source=\"{_dbPath}\"";
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(path);//
#if DEBUG
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(s=>System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s));
#endif
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserReferencesData>()
                .HasOne<UserReferencesMetadata>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MetadataId);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<UserReferencesData> UserReferencesData
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual DbSet<UserReferencesMetadata> UserReferencesMetadata
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

When I execute insert query in SQLite db browser row is added. But second one returns 0 rows (I logged queries which are used by Entity Framework):

```
  INSERT INTO "UserReferencesData" ("BoolValue", "ColumnId", "ColumnType", "DateValue", "DecimalValue", "DoubleValue", "IntValue", "MetadataId", "RowId", "StringValue")
  VALUES (null, 'c6c653c5-3fd3-4c54-ae0d-d5565b3cb725', '1', null, null, null, null, '-2', '1', 'asdf');
  SELECT "Id"
  FROM "UserReferencesData"
  WHERE changes() = 1 AND "rowid" = last_insert_rowid();
```

If I switch to different table and then execute second query again it then pops a list of ids.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with naming, in particular `RowId`.

```
public int RowId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

changed it to `RowKeyId` and it now works fine.